# Presto query Array of Rows

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, presto

So I have a hive external table with schema looks like this :

```
{
.
.
`x` string,
`y` ARRAY<struct<age:string,cId:string,dmt:string>>,
`z` string
}
```

So basically I need to query a column(column "y") which is array of nested json,
I can see data of column "y" from hive, but data in that column seems invisible to presto, even though presto knows schema of this field, like this:

```
array(row(age varchar,cid varchar,dmt varchar))
```

As you can see presto already knows this field is array of row.

Notes:

1.The table is a hive external table.

2.I get schema of field "y" by using ODBC driver, but data is just all empty, however I can see something like this in hive :
[{"age":"12","cId":"bx21hdg","dmt":"120"}]

3.Presto queries hivemetastore for schema.

4.Table was stored as parquet format.

So how can I see my data in field "y" please?

Comment: Are you trying to query through an ODBC driver or using the Presto CLI?

Comment: Presto allows you to join on Arrays using the unnest function, but I'm not clear if that is the result you are intending?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below. This should work in Presto.

"If the array element is a row data type, the result is a table with one column for each row field in the element data type. The result table column data types match the corresponding array element row field data types"

```
select
    y,age,cid,dmt
from
    table
    cross join UNNEST(y)  AS  nested_data(age,cid,dmt)
```

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0055064.html